# Laravel 5.1 set config through db

Tags: php, database, app-config, laravel-5.1

In laravel there are some config files which could be controlled / set with .env file for developing. My question is it possible to set the production values through a db table for example a settings_mail and settings_app table. I need this so that the admin when nessesery could change Some value in a view and doesn't need entering the code

Answer (score 1):

Create a settings table, like this:

| name | value | category |
| --- | --- | --- |
| hostname | smpt.example.com | mail |
| address | San José | general |

Create a setting model based in table structure:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Setting extends Model
{
    /**
     * The table associated with the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'settings';

    protected $name = '';
    protected $value = '';
    protected $category = '';
}
```

Load the settings to be accessible at entire application:

```
// app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php
public function boot(){
    $settings = App\Setting::lists('name', 'value')->all();
    config()->set('settings', $settings);
}
```

Now, get some config:

```
$address = config('settings.address');
```